# Highlighting syntax in a html text editor

Tags: html, syntax, highlighting

All,

In a html textarea is it possible to hightlight c and cpp syntax.If do please indicated an example code for it.

int main()

Int should be highlighted in this case since it is a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea&sess=ba6469857a2ab4dacc7dc4a7b65545f5
and
http://codepress.sourceforge.net/
are two very good options. I'm a fan of the first, but it's more work to set up.

Answer (score 1):

you would need a scripting language (like PHP or JavaScript) to parse the text in the textarea and surround the keywords with a tag such as  word . Then in your css you can add a style for class keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) Editor!

Support over 110 languages